# Сортировка Items в RadioGroup

Tags: delphi

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно каким-либо образом провести сортировку Items в RadioGroup, например по алфавиту (конечно с ненарушением привязки индексов)?
С развитием приложения, элементов становится все больше, а менять индексы, каждый раз при добавлении в середину списка нового элемента – не очень хочется.

Comment: Индекс - есть ничто иное как номер по порядку, меняя порядок меняется номер! Зачем вам нужен индекс?

Comment: В том то и дело, я не хочу менять индекс... Я хочу чтоб не нарушалась в элементах не нарушалась сортировка по алфавитупри добавлении  нового элемента

Comment: А что тогда вы хотите? Я понял чего вы НЕ хотите но не понял что хотите. И при чем тут индекс к сортировке?

Comment: допустим, есть список городов (в RadioGroup): Ашхабад, Киев, Тула (с индексами соответственно 0, 1, 2), при добавлении например города "Мадрид", я хочу чтоб у него индекс был "3", а в списке он шел **НЕ** после Тула, а после "Киев"  (точно как с сортировкой в обычной БД, в которой есть индексы, а данные можно сортировать как угодно)

Comment: Нет, считайте что индекс == номер по порядку -1 ! зачем вам Индекс? Сохраните Ваше значение в объект `RadioGroup1.Items.AddObject('Мадрид',TObject(3));` и соответственно получите ваше значение из объекта `integer(RadioGroup1.Items.Objects[RadioGroup1.ItemIndex])`

Comment: индекс вообще-то для доступа к элементу... Ну если нельзя, то нельзя

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Индекс это просто порядковый номер в списке. Его нельзя сохранить при пересортировке.

Вариант 1:
Сохраните значения в объект `RadioGroup1.Items.AddObject('Мадрид', TObject(3));` и соответственно получите ваше значение из объекта `Integer(RadioGroup1.Items.Objects[RadioGroup1.ItemIndex])`

Вариант 2:
Храните данные отдельно, а RadioGroup1 используйте только для их отображения. При действиях пользователя с RadioGroup1 сохраняйте изменения в данных, а при изменении данных (например пересортировке) динамически перестраивайте RadioGroup1.